# $G$ acts faithfully on $\Omega$, $A\leq G$, $A$ transitive on $\Omega$. Then $|C_G(A)|$ is a divisor of $|\Omega|$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

$G$ acts faithfully on $\Omega$, $A\leq G$, $A$ transitive on $\Omega$. Then $|C_G(A)|$ is a divisor of $|\Omega|$. If in addition $A$ is abelian then $C_G(A)=A$. $G$ and $\Omega$ are finite.

Let $\Gamma:\Omega\times G \to \Omega$ be the action. Then the restriction $\Theta$ of $\Gamma$ to $\Omega\times A$ is an action and we are told it is transitive. Let $|\Omega|=n$. $\Gamma$ induces a homomorphism $\Gamma':G\to S_n$ that is one to one. Also $\Theta$ induces a homomorphism $\Theta':A\to S_n$ which is the restriction of $\Gamma'$ to $A$. Therefor as $\Gamma'$ is one to one so is $\Theta'$, that is $\Theta$ is faithful.

The image of $G$ under $\Gamma'$ is isomorphic to $G$ and a subgroup of $S_n$. Hence $|G|$ divides $n!$ (1). Also, if $\alpha\in\Omega$ and $A_\alpha$ is the stabilizer of $\alpha$ in $A$ then $|\Omega|=|\alpha^A|=  |A|/|A_\alpha|=|A|/|G_\alpha\cap A|$ (2) because of the transitivity of $A$. Aside from this I don't find any further equations to help me prove the statement. Could somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something but what do you mean by "image of $G$ under $\Theta'$"? Did you mean $\Gamma'$? Because $\Theta'$ is not a function defined on $G$.

Comment: It was a typo. It's "under $\Gamma'$". I already corrected it.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, my answer is meant to be a hint, together with why you would think that this is the right approach to take.

Answer (score 2):

First, we need that $C_G(A)$ acts semi-regularly on $\Omega$, i.e., no non-identity element of $C_G(A)$ stabilizes a point on $\Omega$. To see this, let $g\in C_G(A)$ stabilize a point $x\in \Omega$. Since $A$ is transitive on $\Omega$, for any $y\in \Omega$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $xa=y$. But then $g^a=a$, but as is standard, if $g$ stabilizes $x$ then $g^a$ stabilizes $xa=y$. Thus $g$ stabilizes $\Omega$, and $g=1$. This proves that $C_G(A)$ acts semi-regularly on $\Omega$.

Each orbit has length $|C_G(A)|$, by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, and so $|C_G(A)|$ divides $|\Omega|$, as needed.

Comment: $xa_i=x_i$, $i=1,2,...,n$, $xg=x$, $x_ig=xa_ig=xga_i=xa_i=x_i$, $g\in G_{x_i}$ for all $i$, for all $i$ $H_x\leq G_{x_i}$.

Comment: But $\Omega=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$. Then the elements of $H_x$ act like the identity permutation on $\Omega$. SORRY, $H=C_G(A)$.

Comment: Right. So the elements of $C_G(A)$ stabilize every point in $\Omega$. Since $G$ acts faithfully on $\Omega$...

Comment: $H_x=1$ for all $x\in C_\Omega(H)$.

Comment: $H_x=1$ for all $x\in \Omega$. Thus $C_G(A)$ acts semi-regularly, i.e., fixed-point-freely, on $\Omega$. So if the orbits of $H$ on $\Omega$ are all the same size, then you are done. I've added the next part to the answer.

Comment: $a=1$. But we said $g$ fixes $x$. $g\in H$ does not mean $g$ fixes $x$!

Comment: Yes, I replaced that comment with the correct next stage, sorry.

Comment: $H:= C_G(A)$, $x\in \Omega$, $|x^H|=|H|/|H_x|$. But $H_x=1$ by semi-regularity. So, $|x^H|=|H|$. I.e. all orbits have the same size, namely $|H|$. So $|\Omega|=|H|q$ for some integer $q$ and $|H|$ divides $|\Omega|$ as was to be proved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've now edited the answer so it gives a full proof.

Comment: And why should $C_G(A)=A$ if $A$ is abelian?

Comment: If $A$ is abelian then $A\leq C_G(A)$, so all of the statements you have proved about $C_G(A)$ hold for $A$. You should be able to show that $A$ is regular and $C_G(A)=A$ then.

Comment: Of course $A$ is regular because it is a subgroup of $C_G(A)$. But how do I prove the orbit of $x$ under $A$ is equal to the orbit of $x$ under $C_G(A)$?

Comment: I guess you have done this already, but what is the orbit of $x$ under $A$?

Comment: Yes, after posting I realized ($H:= C_G(A)$) $A\leq H$ implies two things: $x^A\subseteq x^H$. But $x^A=\Omega$ ($A$ transitive). Hence $x^H=\Omega$. And $A_x\leq H_x$. But $H_x=1$ as was proved. Hence $A_x=1$. From this $|\Omega|$ can be computed in two ways and $|A|=|H|$ results.

Comment: It's quicker even to note that $|C_G(A)|$ divides $|\Omega|$, $|A|\geq |\Omega|$, and $A\leq C_G(A)$.

Comment: I see. Well, again thanks a lot.